# Duplication occurring during XML serialization of Class Object

Tags: xml, class, object, xml-serialization, stringwriter

I'm trying to serialize a class object into XML but the result ends up having it doubled.  I pass the object into the function only once but duplicates by the time it passes through serialization.  When debugging, I noticed that my `StringWriter` has its `CoreNewLine` field set to Length = 2.  I keep thinking that's the issue but don't know how to work a way to changing it.  Is there something else I'm missing in regards to my serialization?

**My XML Serialization Function**

```
Public Shared Function ToXml(ByVal obj As Object) As String
    Try
        Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(obj.[GetType]())

        Dim stringWrit As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
        Using writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWrit)
            serializer.Serialize(stringWrit, obj)
            Return stringWrit.ToString()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

        DumpException(ex)
        Return ex.ToString()
    End Try

End Function
```

**My Class Object**

```
<Serializable>
Public Class SPFolderOver

Public _files As List(Of SPFile)

Public _folders As List(Of SPFolderOver)

Public _name As String

Public _fullPath As String

<NonSerialized>
<XmlIgnore>
Public _props As Dictionary(Of EmailProperty, String)

Public _sp As Sharepoint

Public Property SPFiles() As List(Of SPFile)
    Get
        Return _files
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of SPFile))
        _files = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SPFolders() As List(Of SPFolderOver)
    Get
        Return _folders
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of SPFolderOver))
        _folders = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Property FolderName() As String
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _name = value
    End Set
End Property

<XmlIgnore>
Public Property Properties() As Dictionary(Of EmailProperty, String)
    Get
        Return _props
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Dictionary(Of EmailProperty, String))
        _props = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Folder() As Object
    Get
        'Return _folderObj
        Return Nothing
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
        '_folderObj = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Property FullPath() As String
    Get
        Return _fullPath
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _fullPath = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Property SP() As Sharepoint
    Get
        Return _sp
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Sharepoint)
        _sp = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  Just changed the object fields from `Public` to `Private`.